# How to replace categorical values with numerical values?

Tags: python, pandas

In dataframe all the values are of type `object` eg: `>20`,`<1`,`>5` etc.
Upperbound = `35` and Lowerbound = `0` So if the value in column is `<1` then I want to replace that value by taking average i.e (0(lowerbound value)+ 1)/2 = 0.5

Similarly if value is `>20` then I want to replace that value by (20+35(upperbound value))/2=27.5

How can I convert existing dataframe to required form. Note: values in the `col1` are strings and not numerical values.

Existing dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ['>20', '<5', '<1','>10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
      col1  
0     >20     
1     <5
2     <1
3     >10
4     100-200
5     10-20
```

I want to convert above `df` to:

```
      col1  
0     27.5     <--- (20+35)/2
1     2.5      <--- (5+0)/2
2     0.5      <--- (1+0)/2
3     22.5     <--- (10+35)/2
4     150      <--- (100+200)/2
5     15       <--- (10+20)/2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by substrings and then [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html):

```
df['col2'] = pd.eval(df['col1'].replace(['>','<'], ['35+','0+'], regex=True)) / 2
print (df)
  col1  col2
0  >20  27.5
1   <5   2.5
2   <1   0.5
3  >10  22.5
```

EDIT:

```
df['col2'] = pd.eval(df['col1'].replace(['>','<','-'], ['35+','0+','+'], regex=True)) / 2
print (df)
      col1  col2
0      >20  27.5
1       <5   2.5
2       <1   0.5
3      >10  22.5
4  100-200   150
5    10-20    15
```

EDIT:

Probl solution above is it working only to 100rows (see [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16289)), so need alternative solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv('train_jqd04QH(1).csv', usecols=['experience', 'company_size'])


s1 = df['experience'].replace(['>','<', '-'], ['35+','0+', '+'], regex=True)

#added anothr repalce string, `\+$` is match last + like 1000+
s2 = df['company_size'].replace(['>','<', '-', '/', '\+$'], 
                                ['35+','0+', '+', '+', '+35'], regex=True)

df['experience'] = s1.str.split('+', expand=True).astype(float).mean(axis=1)
df['company_size'] = s2.str.split('+', expand=True).astype(float).mean(axis=1)

print (df.head())

   experience  company_size
0         3.0         300.0
1        14.0           5.0
2         6.0          74.5
3        14.0          74.5
4         8.0           NaN
```

Comment: Also if values in column are `100-200` then can I replace them using (100+200)/2=150 using above technique.

Comment: @stonerock - Yes, only need replace `-` to `+` like `df['col2'] = pd.eval(df['col1'].replace(['>','<', '-'], ['35+','0+','+'], regex=True)) / 2`

Comment: what does `regex=True` does ?

Comment: @stonerock - It is for replace substrings, if omit it it replace only strings. You can check it by `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ['>20', '<5', '<','>', '-', '10-20']})` with `print (df['col1'].replace(['>','<','-'], ['35+','0+', '+'], regex=True))` and `print (df['col1'].replace(['>','<','-'], ['35+','0+', '+']))`

Comment: @stonerock - What is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.23.3 and I am using kaggle private kernel.

Comment: I know, need replace `<` and `>` because `<1` return error in second row in picture

Comment: Maybe problem with last `...`

Comment: what ? I think there is spacing between two values while doing average check the previous screenshot

Comment: @stonerock - like csv ? I cannot copy data from picture ;)

Comment: @stonerock - There was another problematic values in `company_size` column, but I get it, check changed solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for that.

```
df.replace({'>20':27.5, '<5':2.5, '<1':0.5, '>10':22.5})
```

Although I have the feeling that the values that you want to fill in are not well calculated. Are the ranges not as follows:

```
20 - 35 --> 27.5
10 - 20 --> 15
1  -  5 --> 3
0  -  1 --> 0.5
```